# Align flex wrapped elements to bottom of the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following html:

```
<div class="inhaler__animation__container">
    <div class="inhaler__image__wrapper">
        <img src="img/inhaler-only.png" alt="Inhaler animation image" title="Inhaler animation image">
        <div class="inhaler__image__dot__wrapper">
            <img src="img/pdot.png" alt="purple dot - Inhaler animation image" title="purple dot - Inhaler animation image">
            <img src="img/wdot.png" alt="white dot - Inhaler animation image" title="white dot - Inhaler animation image">
            <img src="img/pdot.png" alt="purple dot - Inhaler animation image" title="purple dot - Inhaler animation image">
            <img src="img/wdot.png" alt="white dot - Inhaler animation image" title="white dot - Inhaler animation image">
            <img src="img/pdot.png" alt="purple dot - Inhaler animation image" title="purple dot - Inhaler animation image">
            <img src="img/wdot.png" alt="white dot - Inhaler animation image" title="white dot - Inhaler animation image">
            <img src="img/pdot.png" alt="purple dot - Inhaler animation image" title="purple dot - Inhaler animation image">
            <img src="img/wdot.png" alt="white dot - Inhaler animation image" title="white dot - Inhaler animation image">
            <img src="img/pdot.png" alt="purple dot - Inhaler animation image" title="purple dot - Inhaler animation image">
            <img src="img/wdot.png" alt="white dot - Inhaler animation image" title="white dot - Inhaler animation image">
            <img src="img/pdot.png" alt="purple dot - Inhaler animation image" title="purple dot - Inhaler animation image">
            <img src="img/wdot.png" alt="white dot - Inhaler animation image" title="white dot - Inhaler animation image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following css:

```
.inhaler__animation__container > .inhaler__image__wrapper > .inhaler__image__dot__wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

But the dot images which are the child elements of `.inhaler__image__dot__wrapper` still spread out vertically , i want them to be stacked on top of each other , but that's not whats happening here, how do i prevent the dot images to not be spread out vertically ?

see image below::-

[image]

So how do i prevent the dot images from being spread out vertically ? I.E they should be aligned to the bottom of the grey area.

DEMO can be found [HERE](http://peckingatcode.net/Animation-inhaler-v1/inhale.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the `align-content` property.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content):

> The CSS align-content property defines how the browser distributes
>   space between and around content items along the cross-axis of their
>   container, which is serving as a flexbox container.

Just add `align-content: flex-end;` to the flex container

```
.inhaler__animation__container > .inhaler__image__wrapper > .inhaler__image__dot__wrapper {
    ...
    align-content: flex-end;
}
```